# Listing Docker Images using Google Artifact Registry Python Client

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-api-python-client, google-artifact-registry

I'm trying to list the docker images in a particular repo using the google artifact registry Python client.

Is there any way to list only the names of unique images in a repo? The [list_docker_images](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/artifactregistry/latest/google.cloud.artifactregistry_v1.services.artifact_registry.ArtifactRegistryClient#google_cloud_artifactregistry_v1_services_artifact_registry_ArtifactRegistryClient_list_docker_images) function lists all versions of all images from a particular repo.

Maybe the metadata parameter is a potential solution?

Also, is it possible to list images from a virual docker repo, so that it will list images from the upstream repos?

Comment: No, you have to perform the filter yourselves

Answer (score 0):

You can use [listPackages](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/artifactregistry/latest/google.cloud.artifactregistry_v1.services.artifact_registry.ArtifactRegistryClient#google_cloud_artifactregistry_v1_services_artifact_registry_ArtifactRegistryClient_list_packages) to get a list of artifacts without per-version information. This is not docker specific and will work for all Artifact Registry formats.